# is there any other ways to solved the react-router-dom Links?

Tags: reactjs

import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Routes,
Route,
Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
i used this import to use {Link} in another component and i used it but it says 'Link is defined but never used' in app.js

Comment: Can you show your full code? Also, what version of `react router` are you using?

Comment: These warnings are per file. If your other component is in other file it does not count for used in app.js

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.